# How to access to google project from ui rather than link get from eclipse console

Tags: spring

I have developed a tool for handling google sheet using spring boot with google sheet api. When I run the application from UI ,then eclipse console will show a link for OAuth authentication so that to get data in UI [Eclipse console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zUQ3.png).I need to get back to console and take the link to browser for authentication. So my question is how to authenticate it through UI rather than going to console manually.
I selected react js as UI, and I added GoogleLogin to it
`
This tool is requir a google account to access
<GoogleLogin

```
        clientId="my client id"
        redirectUri="http://localhost:8888/Callback"
        scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
        responseType="code"
        accessType="offline"
        buttonText="Choose account"


        onSuccess=""

        onFailure="" ></GoogleLogin>
        </div>`
```

even though react js code worked,i will get the sheet data only after authenticating using link given in console.Please help me to solve this

Answer (score 0):

You may redirect it directly but it would only work in case you are having that url working.
Let suppose, I'm hosting my application on http://localhost:8080/myProject then it would be redirect you to some url, you would be get that using this way.

- Generate Credentials.json file while keeping redirect url blank.
- Put this file to resources
- Run project again
- It will give you the response url, Do something for mapping that URL to your needed re-directional url.

Let me know if you need anything more in this.